# Can't Access all JSON Object exhaustively

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I was trying to access all the members form the JSON object was not able to access them all, I have retrieved 15 key data from the database it is there in the JSON object cannot retrieve it into the String object.Only 8 are accessible and rest of the objects are not accessible .

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject userData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        Toast.makeText(context,"json object "+jsonObject,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(context,"result "+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(context,"userdata "+userData,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        username =userData.getString(Config.KEY_USERNNAME);
        email = userData.getString(Config.KEY_EMAIL);
        fathername=userData.getString(Config.KEY_FATHERNAME);
        mothername=userData.getString(Config.KEY_MOTHERNAME);
        studentcontact=userData.getString(Config.KEY_STUDENTCONTACT);
        parentcontact=userData.getString(Config.KEY_PARENTCONTACT);
        stu_class=userData.getString(Config.KEY_CLASS);

        tuition=userData.getString(Config.KEY_TUITION);
        Toast.makeText(context,tuition,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        address=userData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
        Toast.makeText(context,address,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        fees=userData.getString(Config.KEY_FEES);
        feesstatus=userData.getString(Config.KEY_FEESSTATUS);
        rankbatch=userData.getString(Config.KEY_RANKBATCH);
        ranktuition=userData.getString(Config.KEY_RANKTUITION);
        teacherremark=userData.getString(Config.KEY_TEACHERREMARK);
        joindate=userData.getString(Config.KEY_JOINDATE);
        dob=userData.getString(Config.KEY_DOB);
        Toast.makeText(context,dob,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

getJSON Object return me

```
{  
   "result":[  
      {  
         "username":"Akshay  Kumar",
         "email":"example@example.com",
         "fathername":"FatherName",
         "mothername":"MotherName ",
         "studentcontact":"9999999999",
         "parentcontact":"9999999999",
         "class":"BTECH",
         "tuition":"Computer",
         "address":"Address",
         "fees":"5000",
         "feesstatus":"paid",
         "rankbatch":"2",
         "ranktuition":"2",
         "teacherremark":"Good Student",
         "joindate":"2016-07-04",
         "dob":"2016-01-01"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is my config class

```
    public class Config {
    public static final String DATA_URL =  "http://someurl.com/xyz.php";
    public static final String KEY_USERNNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String KEY_FATHERNAME ="fathername";
    public static final String KEY_MOTHERNAME = "mothername";
    public static final String KEY_STUDENTCONTACT ="studentcontact";
    public static final String KEY_PARENTCONTACT = "parentcontact";
    public static final String KEY_CLASS="class";
    public static final String KEY_TUITION ="tuition";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS="addresss";
    public static final String KEY_FEES="fees";
    public static final String KEY_FEESSTATUS="feesstatus";
    public static final String KEY_RANKBATCH="rankbatch";
    public static final String KEY_RANKTUITION="ranktuition";
    public static final String KEY_TEACHERREMARK="teacherremark";
    public static final String KEY_JOINDATE="joindate";
    public static final String KEY_DOB="dob";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

This is my code and in this the upper 3 Toasts showing the jsonObject, result and userData displays the whole data retrieved from the database .The Toast below tuition also display the data of tuition string but after the tuition string no data is retrieved it shows empty .
Now i am not getting how to retrieve my other data from the JSON object.

Comment: You need to share your `JSONObject`, if you can't access some properties it means you are doing it the wrong way, without the original object we cannot tell what's wrong... Also, share your `Config` class

Comment: getJSON Object returns me  
   {"result":[{"username":"Akshay  Kumar","email":"example@example.com","fathername":"FatherName","mothername":"MotherName ","studentcontact":"9999999999","parentcontact":"9999999999","class":"BTECH","tuition":"Computer","address":"Address","fees":"5000","feesstatus":"paid","rankbatch":"2","ranktuition":"2","teacherremark":"Good Student","joindate":"2016-07-04","dob":"2016-01-01"}]}

Comment: Post your `Config` class too